# Angular material version for angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm building an angular5 application for this I need angular material, which version of angular material compatible with angular 5 application and how to install it.

Comment: Use Angular 6. Material is a schematics and can be easily imported.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With Angular 5, you can use angular material 5. Execute the following commands to install ver `5.2.5` of `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk`:

```
npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.5 
npm install --save @angular/cdk@5.2.5
```

Comment: what is the use of angular cdk

Comment: The Angular CDK gives developers solid, well-tested tools to add common interaction patterns with minimal effort. Read more about it here: https://blog.angular.io/a-component-dev-kit-for-angular-9f06e3b4b3b4

Comment: @Faisal I am currently on angular version 6.1.10 and I recently downloaded the latest version of /material and /cdk. My question is, will version 8.0.0 of /material be compatible with version 6.1.10 of Angular??

Comment: @javan.rajpopat It's not compatible.

Comment: @Faisal Thank you for the fast response! :)

Answer (score 4):

For the newer version of angular v.6.0 
you can use :

```
npm install --save @angular/material@6.2.1
npm install --save @angular/cdk@6.0.0
```

One new command is added in the latest CLI ver. (you need to update to the latest ver of CLI)

```
ng add @angular/material
```

this will automatically add the compatible ver in the package.json file.

Comment: Apart from material and cdk, you might also need to install @angular/animations.